# Can I retrieve a locale independent application label from the Android PackageManager?

Tags: android

I'm using `PackageManager.getApplicationLabel(ApplicationInfo)` to retrieve application labels.

It looks like the label that is returned depends on the Locale set for the phone.

For instance with the music app I get "Music" in English, vs. "Musica" if I have my locale set to Spanish.

Is there a way to get the default application label (perhaps as defined in `strings.xml`)?

I want to be able to retrieve an application label for each app that is independent of locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "application label for each app that is independent of locale" in Android. After all, in your own application, you will notice that you are not providing such a label.

I would flip the question around: what is there that you *are* putting in `AndroidManifest.xml` that would meet your needs? Then, find out how to access that data from the `PackageManager`.